# Button Command inside Listview not firing

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I've a ListView that displays an ObservableCollection. 
Each item of the Listview has a button and a Command with a Binding of "AggiungiCommand" and a CommandParameter.
When I click over the button, the command doesn't fire. 
Here's the code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns: …
             x:Name="MieiAcquistiViewPage"
...
    <StackLayout CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="True">
        <StackLayout.BindingContext>
            <local:MieiAcquistiViewModel/>
        </StackLayout.BindingContext>

          <ListView x:Name="listView"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding AcquistiList}"
                      ItemTapped="listView_ItemTapped"
                      CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Frame Style="{StaticResource frameListView}" >
                                <StackLayout Margin="-15">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Articolo.Descrizione}" />
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                                 HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >

                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                     HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                                            <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                                       Text="{Binding Prezzo, StringFormat='{}{0:€ 0.00}'}"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                        </StackLayout>

                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                     HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center">                                    

                                                <Label Text="{Binding QtaEdit}" 
                                                       TextColor="Black"
VerticalTextAlignment="Center"                                                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                                            <Button x:Name="addButton" 
                                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                    Text="+"         
                                                    Command="{Binding AggiungiCommand, Source={x:Reference MieiAcquistiViewPage}}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
</StackLayout>
...
</ContentPage/>
```

In my View model class:

```cs
        public MieiAcquistiViewModel()
        {    
            AggiungiCommand = new Command<RigaStoricoModel>(AggiungiArticolo);            
        }

        public void AggiungiArticolo(RigaStoricoModel prodotto) 
        {
            // some stuff
        }

        public ICommand AggiungiCommand { private set; get; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Command="{Binding MieiAcquistiViewModel.AggiungiCommand, Source={x:Reference MieiAcquistiViewPage}}` to `Command="{Binding BindingContext.AggiungiCommand, Source={x:Reference MieiAcquistiViewPage}}`. Note how I replaced `MieiAcquistiViewModel` with `BindingContext.`.

Assuming that you are referencing the page there and you want to access the command in the view model backing that page.

Comment: I've applied your suggestion, but I get the following exception:  `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 108:49. Can not find the object referenced by MieiAcquistiViewPage.BindingContext'.` . I added some other details on my main question.

Comment: My bad, I mixed up the syntax :) I've updated my answer, please try that

Comment: Ok, now there's any exception, but unfortunately the command is still not firing. Is there anything about the binding with viewmodel?

Comment: I see you set the view model only to the `StackLayout`. Either give your `StackLayout` a name and reference that from the binding or move the view model up to your page

Comment: Thx, it works!!! I didn't know I had to reference the binding of stackLayout.

Comment: Read a blog post from me about it here for some more background info: https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/databinding-scope-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to prefix the AggiungiCommand with 'MieiAcquistiViewModel' in your binding if you already attached your viewmodel. You can do it like this:

```
Command="{Binding  Source={x:Reference MieiAcquistiViewPage}, Path=BindingContext.AggiungiCommand,Mode=TwoWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```